# Как вставить HTML в селектор, который подгрузился по AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как вставить HTML в селектор, который подгрузился по AJAX? Такой вариант не работает:

```
$('.selector').html('something');
```

Comment: на сколько я помню, селектор по классу возвращает массив объектом с таким классом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну видимо после того как данные прибыли их нужно сначала вставить в какой-нибудь div через append, а потом разбираться с ними.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  success: function(data){
          alert( "Прибыли данные:");
          $('#container').append(data);
          $('.selector').html('something');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

У функции *$* есть второй (опциональный) аргумент, позволяющий задать контекст для запроса. Попробуйте

$('.selector', received_html).html('something');